# Dimensionality reduction of vectors with null values

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, missing-data, vector-space-models

I have vectors of same length where each entry can have the value 0, 1 or null.

`V = {[0,1,1,1,null,0], [null,1,0,null,0,1], ...}`

How can I perform a dimensionality reduction of these vectors into a lower dimensional space (in this case 2d)?

Comment: The simplest solution is to replace the null values by an outlier like -1. The dimensionality reduction will work well, but it will consider the null as closer to 0 than 1. If you want to separate null values even more, you can replace them by more extreme values like 10 or -10.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Drop rows that have null values.
- Impute the null values.
- Pick a dimensionality reduction algorithm that can handle null values. One example is NIPALS (Nonlinear Iterative Partial Least Squares) algorithm. That algorithm is discussed in "[Multivariate Analysis of Quality: An Introduction](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Multivariate+Analysis+of+Quality%3A+An+Introduction-p-9780471974284)" by Martens and Martens

Answer (score 0):

This is a data wrangling problem where you will need to experiment and it's even better if you know your data.

- If you suspect that the null means 0 but the user just omitted it
  then replace it for zero.
- If you can work with negative numbers replace the nulls with -1 as Nicolas mentioned unless -1 is a value that your numbers reach naturally.
- If these nulls mean something important for your dataset
  you can create another column B where column A is null.
- Another thing I can think of is that if you have categorical values, then you can one-hot-encode these columns.